# Increase a field in multiple records with cakePHP functions

Tags: php, cakephp

I'll explain the situation.

I have some 'modules', and one of the fields is the 'position' in the main page.  If I create/edit a module with a specific position I want to check the rest of the modules which have a higher or equal position and move them one position forward.

In my solution I use the `query()` function of the Model.

How?

In my Module Model I have a function...

```
function moveModules( $includedPosition ){

    if( !is_numeric( $includedPosition ) ){
        return false;
    }

    $sql = 
          "UPDATE modules "
        . " SET modules.position = modules.position + 1 "
        . " WHERE modules.position >= $includedPosition "
    ;

    $result = $this->query(  $sql );        

}
```

I can use this function in the `beforeSave()` or in the controller wherever I want but...

**I want to ask if exists a possible solution without using a custom Query.**

Thanks

SOLUTION ( Thanks Headshota )

```
function moveModules( $includedPosition ){

    if( !is_numeric( $includedPosition ) ){
        return false;
    }

    $this->updateAll(array('Module.position'=>'Module.position + 1'), array('Module.position >='=>$includedPosition ));


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using updateAll

```
$this->Model->updateAll(array('Model.item'=>'Model.item+1'), array('Model.id'=>1));
```